# Is there a way to extract my source code from boxfuse?

Tags: java, cloudcaptain

Forgive a non technical app owner for what’s probably a stupid question, I worked with a back end developer a year ago to apply some fixes to my app but didn’t get his code directly from him (oblivious). Now I’m working with a new back end developer and we need that code. We used boxfuse to push changes, is there a way to get the code from boxfuse or are we screwed?!

Answer (score 3):

I have never used BoxFuse, but judging from the [documentation](https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/) it appears that you create BoxFuse "app" from a payload which (for a JVM-based app) will be a JAR or WAR file.  A JAR / WAR file typically consists of compiled code (".class" files) and other resources, but not Java source code.

In other words, the source code won't be in the BoxFuse app.  I'd say you are probably screwed<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - Unless you / the new developer are prepared to work with decompiled code, and its associated problems.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The answers is it depends. If this is a Node.js app, you will be able to find the source by peeling open the layers of your image using a tool like 7-zip.

On the other hand if it is a JVM app, then the best you can get is a decompiled version. Extract the jar or war from the image by peeling open its layers using 7-zip and then run it through a decompiler. Not great, but much better than nothing!

Comment: Thanks it’s a Node.js app I’ll give these a go!!

Comment: @Gabi - if your app is Javascript, you shouldn't have labeled this question "java"!!